# Automating my Python script to add next months value from an API request

Tags: python, api, automation

I am fetching some data from an API (Available at the site: http://prognos.konj.se/PxWeb/pxweb/en/SenastePrognosen/SenastePrognosen__f06_rantorochvaxelkurser/F0604.px/)
with the following code:

```
import requests

url = "http://prognos.konj.se/PxWeb/api/v1/sv/SenastePrognosen/f06_rantorochvaxelkurser/F0604.px"

querystring = {
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "variabel",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "F0604Repo_u"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "period",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "321",   
          "322",
          "323",
          "324"      ######## Next month I would like to add the value   325 ########
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "px"
    # "format": "csv"
  }
}

response = requests.post(url, json=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

The relevant output data [coming from: print(response.text) ] in my case is then:

```
DATA=
-0.2500 -0.2500 -0.2500 0.0000 
;
```

Assume I got that data standing at june 2021.

In july 2021, I would like to get data for 5 months, updating the code part:

```
    "values": [
      "321",   
      "322",
      "323",
      "324", 
      "325"    ##### This line got added for this month #####
```

Obviously, I would like to do this automatically in my script every month, i.e. not having to hard code it. Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: how does e.g. `325` get generated?

Comment: First i fetched the "querystring" in the code from: http://prognos.konj.se/PxWeb/pxweb/en/SenastePrognosen/SenastePrognosen__f06_rantorochvaxelkurser/F0604.px/ (I edited this in the post now, and you will have to fill in variable, unit and period in the provided website to see the code that I posted) and then for the uppcoming months I would add 325 manually in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here could be solved by just generating your `querystring` at runtime:

```py
query = { # note renamed as it's not really a string.
  "query": [
    ... # as above
    {
      "code": "period",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": []
      }
    }
  ],
  ... # as above
}
query[1]["values"] = gen_months()
```

Where `gen_months()` is some function which generates the right values for the months you are interested in.  Naively this would work:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def gen_months():
    return [str(m) for m in range(321, 320 + datetime.now().month)]
```

But I imagine there is some more sensible relationship between this number and the current month.

Do note that if you get an extra month's data every time your requests will get bigger and bigger and bigger until, presumably, you get blocked.  It might make more sense only to get the *latest* month's data and do the concatenation yourself.